# Google sheets: Compare a number with a range of numbers and pick the closest lower number

Tags: google-sheets, filter, match, vlookup, min

I have a random number in range 300-450, like 418. Then, I have 5 cells with numbers 300, 330, 360, 390, 420.

I need to find out the nearest lower number of 418. So, It should refer to the cell with number 390.

Is there an easy way? Thank you.

Comment: sorry my bad i thought you need the cell refrence the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73223481/19529694) is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if 390 is your desired result use:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2, A1:A5, 1, 1)
```

[image]

if your 5 cells are in row you can use `HLOOKUP`

---

otherwise, the closest is 420:

```
=FILTER(A1:A5, ABS(C2-A1:A5)=MIN(ABS(C2-A1:A5)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I used VLOOKUP. It is simple and does everything I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Or take a look at the [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1djtzpDdSSl2szkdOQ6o7TyxeW8wPEs8bJmPEhXXTjHw/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A,MATCH(MIN(FILTER(ArrayFormula(IF($A$3:$A="",,D2-$A$3:$A)),ArrayFormula(IF($A$3:$A="",,D2-$A$3:$A))>0)),FILTER(ArrayFormula(IF($A$3:$A="",,D2-$A$3:$A)),ArrayFormula(IF($A$3:$A="",,D2-$A$3:$A))>0),0),1)
```

[image]